# How could I avoid data type overflow in Simulink?

Tags: simulink

I have an overflow issue in Simulink, I made a model in Simulink, see the attached picture.

If the port 2 (const ticks_des) is 256 then the memory block overflows and the time_over_flg cannot be active to trigger a reset. How could I change my model, so to be possible to avoid data type overflow?

[image: Value comparator Simulink]

Comment: Input port 2 can never be 256.  You've got it defined as a uint8 which has a range of 0 to 255.  And a memory block can never overflow, it just passes its input to its output (delayed by one time period).  Do you mean the summation block overflows?  That can't be avoided if you are trying to add one each time, unless you add some more logic so that it doesn't add 1 if the first input is already at 255.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for data type overflow is using Data Type Conversion block. Add a Data Type Conversion block to the output of input 2. Then ,

In the Data Type Conversion block, the Saturate on integer overflow parameter must be selected. The Data Type Conversion block wraps when the signal is too large to fit into the output data type.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdYeF.png

[see its block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdYeF.png)

Answer (score 0):

The simulink (e.g. summation) block will often have a checkbox to the effect of "saturate on integer overflow."

If it does not, you can fix it yourself by casting the data type of each arithmetic operation to be a data type large enough to contain whatever the biggest value the arithmetic operation might produce.  You would take the modulus of the result of that arithmetic operation with the maximum value of the output data type.

For instance, if you were adding two uint8's together, you would cast each to a uint16 and then take the modulus of that addition with the 255 (ie. finalresult=mod(uint16(a)+uint16(b), 255).